# Load all pages of site with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to have a section of my site all on one page, and load it using URL anchors of parameters.  So, for example, when I click a link, it should load the content part of the page and the rest should stay, like the header.  An example of this would be YouTube or PayPal, and if anyone could explain how these work, that would be nice.  So far, I have tried using <iframe>s, but that requires making the pages anyway.  Is there a way I can generate the pages from jQuery?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: have a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method from Jquery to load content into section on the page.  So for instance, if you have a basic HTML page and created a stub for the section you want to load dynamic content into like so

```
<div id="dynamicSection"></div>
```

Then you can make calls from via ajax to populate content into that div

```
$("#dynamicSection").load("dynamicContent.html");
```

where you dynamicContent.html file would be the HTML stub of data:

```
<h1>I'm your dynamic content</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `$.ajax(...` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

you should not store your data in your view. Only display the active page. You could cache the other pages(data) (in objects) - if needed